# Javascript map() forEach() method not working in succession

Tags: javascript, firefox, map-function

I know its a bit convoluted, but consider this hypothetical:

```
class test {
    points = [[10,15]];
    rotate (angle){
        let deg = angle *= Math.PI/180; //degrees to radians
        this.points.map((point, pointIndex) => point.map((value, axis) => this.points[pointIndex][axis] = axis === 0 ? (this.points[pointIndex][0]*Math.cos(deg)-this.points[pointIndex][1]*Math.sin(deg)):(this.points[pointIndex][1]*Math.cos(deg)+this.points[pointIndex][0]*Math.sin(deg))));

        //This essentially maps the current points to their projections after rotating them by some angle
        //It performs two different operations respective to the two different values in the nested array
    }
}

let foo = new test;
foo.rotate(90);
console.log(foo.points);
```

Running this will return:

> Array [ -15, -14.999999999999998 ]

Which, for arguments sake, is not the intended result.

At first I assumed it had something to do with the use of the "?" operator, but eliminating this and separating the outcomes into their own mapping:

```
class test {
    points = [[10,15]];
    rotate (angle){
        let deg = angle *= Math.PI/180;

        this.points.map((point, pointIndex) => this.points[pointIndex][0]=(this.points[pointIndex][0]*Math.cos(deg)-this.points[pointIndex][1]*Math.sin(deg)));

        this.points.map((point, pointIndex) => this.points[pointIndex][1]=(this.points[pointIndex][1]*Math.cos(deg)+this.points[pointIndex][0]*Math.sin(deg)));
        
    }
}

let foo = new test;
foo.rotate(90);
console.log(foo.points);
```

But this results in the same outcome. However, when running either of line by itself, which, because they are split, affects only the first or second element depending on which is eliminated, the accurate result is returned:

> Array [ -15, 15 ] (if the second line is removed)
> Array [ 10, 10.000000000000002 ] (if the first line is removed)

Both of which return the accurate value of their respective index. ([ -15, 10.000000000000002 ] is correct, taking the first element of the first array and the second of the second.)

For some reason, by running them in succession, something fails.

Thank you in advance.

Edit: The same issue occurs when using forEach().

Comment: Those are improper usages of `map()`.  Map is intended to be used as a transformation method.  You take an array, and you transform all the elements into new things, and collect the results.  You are not collecting the results.  Use `forEach()` instead to just iterate.

Comment: I just tired it, and the same issue occurs when using forEach() instead.

Comment: I'm sure whatever issue is there will still happen.  I'm simply pointing out the method misuse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't access the current object inside an transformation.

```js
class test {
    points = [[10,15]];
    rotate (angle){
        let deg = angle * Math.PI/180; //degrees to radians
        this.points = this.points.map((point) => {
          let newPoint = [0,0];
          newPoint[0] = point[0]*Math.cos(deg)-point[1]*Math.sin(deg);
          newPoint[1] = point[1]*Math.cos(deg)+point[0]*Math.sin(deg);
          return newPoint
        })

        //This essentially maps the current points to their projections after rotating them by some angle
        //It performs two different operations respective to the two different values in the nested array
    }
}

let foo = new test;
foo.rotate(90);
console.log(foo.points);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are transforming one coordinate and then doing to operation for the other one with the new value (not the old one as you should). I think that's the problem.

```
class test {
    points = [[10, 15]];

    rotate (angle){
        let radians = (Math.PI / 180) * angle,
          cos = Math.cos(radians),
          sin = Math.sin(radians);
          
        this.points = this.points.map((p) => {
          return [cos * p[0] + sin * p[1], cos * p[1] - sin * p[0]];
        })
    }
}

let foo = new test;
foo.rotate(90);
console.log(foo.points);
```

[Link to jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/alotropico/gvsq8w0h/24/)